# Cant take to build in iOS after zebrautility: ^0.0.38 added

Tags: ios, flutter, zebra-printers

I'm new to Xcode in a flutter, when I integrated zebrautility plugin in the flutter project, the android module worked fine, and print works.

When I try to run on iPhone, it always throws an error

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): Library not found for -lZSDK_API

Error launching application on Kirubha's iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue in plugin.
Need to add '.a' extension as like ( s.vendored_libraries = 'libZSDK_API.a' )
in zebrautility.podspec