# Printing to Zebra from iOS, how do I fix the error "Library not found for -lZSDK_API"

Tags: flutter, zebra-printers

I'm using the zebrautility, https://pub.dev/packages/zebrautility, to be able to print to a Zebra printer from iOS in Flutter. Building the project results in the error

```
Library not found for -lZSDK_API
```

The only reference I found is at [Cant take to build in iOS after zebrautility: ^0.0.38 added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72225064/cant-take-to-build-in-ios-after-zebrautility-0-0-38-added), but there is no zebrautility.podspec file. There is a Flutter.podspec but this file is generated from another source. (Editing them to the path where the library is located did not make a difference.)

When I try to build from within XCode, I get instead the error,

```
Module 'device_info_plus' not found
```